# How to filter associations in Play Framework CRUD Module

Tags: java, module, associations, playframework, crud

Let's say I have a Cat class which contains a collection of Kittens. I want to be able to list the Kittens according to a given condition, for example, the principal's role. So far, no problem at all, I resolved this issue with an @Before which adds the corresponding filter to the list view.

But now I want to change the edit page for the Cat, so that when it lists the Kittens (remember, in the edit view I can select the Kittens for the selected Cat), it brings only those available for the principal's role. But the default behavior is to retrieve all the Kittens from the database, and that's not what I want.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: I would like to see a tutorial / documentation on how to build something a bit more tailored using basic CRUD building blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Default CRUD module in Play is a basic CRUD which lacks a lot of functionality in several scenarios. The best approach is to download the code of the module (you have it in your local Play deployment, under "modules"), add it to your project as a custom module and modify it as much as you need.

In your scenario, simply go into the part that renders the List view and hack it to use the filters.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know if there exists a simple way to achieve that. I already modified the List view, now I want to modify the show view so that it doesn't list all the associated entities.

Comment: What do you mean by simple? If you mean by enabling some configuration, no, there isn't. You have to manually change the CRUD module for any customization you want. That or create one from scratch :)

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I was trying not to program anything, you know... :P

I thought there was a way to do it, but there's not so much documentation of the CRUD module apart from the basics. I tried extending ObjectField with partial success: it did the filtering but I got a template error. So I guess I'll have to write a new template from stratch...